# Switch php versions on commandline ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, apache, command-line-interface, php-5.6, php-7.1

I have installed php 5.6 and and php 7.1 on my Ubuntu 16.04

I know with Apache as my web server, I can do

```
a2enmod php5.6 #to enable php5
a2enmod php7.1 #to enable php7
```

When I disable php7.1 in Apache modules and enable php 5.6, Apache recognizes the change and uses php 5.6 interpreter as expected.

But when I run internal php web server from the commandline:

```
php -S localhost:8888
```

php handles requests using php 7. So how do I switch between php 5.6 and php 7.1 in the command line ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/705880/how-to-install-php-7

Answer (score 557):

#### Interactive switching mode

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
sudo update-alternatives --config phar
sudo update-alternatives --config phar.phar
```

#### Manual Switching

#### From PHP 5.6 => PHP 7.1

Default PHP 5.6 is set on your system and you need to switch to PHP 7.1.

Apache:

```
$ sudo a2dismod php5.6
$ sudo a2enmod php7.1
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Command Line:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.1
$ sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar7.1
$ sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar7.1
```

#### From PHP 7.1 => PHP 5.6

Default PHP 7.1 is set on your system and you need to switch to PHP 5.6.

Apache:

```
$ sudo a2dismod php7.1
$ sudo a2enmod php5.6
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Command Line:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
```

[Source](https://tecadmin.net/switch-between-multiple-php-version-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6   this commands saved my time.. thanks @StevieG

Comment: I had segmentation fault on apache2 restart. I then found that I had more than one PHP version enabled at a time. I had to disable both 7.1 and 7.2 before enabling 5.6.

Comment: Indeed, I just have used this solution to change `php -v` from 7.2 to 7.1! It is great and simple.

Comment: Great piece of advice is here also - https://askubuntu.com/questions/761713/how-can-i-downgrade-from-php-7-to-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04 . By the way, you can install several php modules - 5.6, 7.0, 7.1, 7.2, for example, and then juggle them, if you get certain errors for a given version of php (for example, `create_function` is no longer supported starting from php 7.2.)

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 I had to do some extra steps to disable other versions or processes will continue to run. # systemctl stop php5.6-fpm | # systemctl disable php5.6-fpm | to get the list of php processes do # ps -ax | grep php

Comment: sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4 worked for me (for switching from 7.0 to 7.4).
Thanks

Comment: `$ sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6` helped me to make the same php versions between `phpinfo()` and `php -v`.

Answer (score 463):

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

should work for all ubuntu versions after **16.04** (**18.04** and **20.04**)

This is what you should see as a response

```
There are 4 choices for the alternative php (providing /usr/bin/php).

  Selection    Path             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/php7.2   72        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/php5.6   56        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/php7.0   70        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/php7.1   71        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/php7.2   72        manual mode
Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Choose the appropriate version

Comment: This one should be the answer

Comment: Why php7.2 two times?

Comment: @SandOfVega this is the output of the command and might display something 2 times if it is the default I guess, but your output might be different.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 gives me "error: no alternatives for php"

Comment: @burzum Works fine on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The ease of switching between versions on Ubuntu 20.04 is just so smooth.

Comment: Don't forget to `a2enmod` / `a2dismod` and restart apache - happened to me.

Comment: @SandOfVega The zeroth path is always currently selected one. Then from first onwards they are all displayed, including the selected one. Note: if you don't have more than one PHP installed, this command will remind you that there are no alternatives, and you won't see the table presented above.

Comment: Funkin love you ma maaannnnnn

Answer (score 39):

in `ubuntu 20.04` switching between `PHP 8.0` and `PHP 7.4` version:

**DOWNGRADE** `PHP 8.0` to `PHP 7.4`

```php
sudo a2dismod php8.0
sudo a2enmod php7.4
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo update-alternatives --config php
sudo update-alternatives --config phar
sudo update-alternatives --config phar.phar
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**UPGRADE** `PHP 7.4` to `PHP 8.0`

```php
sudo a2dismod php7.4
sudo a2enmod php8.0
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo update-alternatives --config php
sudo update-alternatives --config phar
sudo update-alternatives --config phar.phar
sudo service apache2 restart
```

check the changes:

1. run `php -v` in the console and you will got:

> PHP 8.0.3 (cli) (built: Mar  5 2021 07:54:13) ( NTS )
> Copyright (c) The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v4.0.3, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
> with Zend OPcache v8.0.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

OR

> PHP 7.4.16 (cli) (built: Mar  5 2021 07:54:38) ( NTS )
> Copyright (c) The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
> with Zend OPcache v7.4.16, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

2. add a PHP file in your runnable local environment like `/var/www/html/` path by adding `phpinfo();` and get PHP info in the browser (in top of the page the version of PHP is available to see)

Comment: Is there no change to php-config or phpize like in the other examples?  Something like sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config8.0

Answer (score 35):

To list all available versions and choose from them :

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

Or do manually

```
sudo a2dismod php7.1 // disable
sudo a2enmod php5.6  // enable
```

Comment: Your manual option here isn't doing the same as the first one. The first one is setting the php executable that will be used when invoking `php` from the command line. The manual option that you've given here is switching the php module that will be used by apache2

Answer (score 19):

I actually wouldn't recommend using `a2enmod` for php 5 or 7. I would use `update-alternatives`. You can do `sudo update-alternatives --config php` to set which system wide version of PHP you want to use. This makes your command line and apache versions work the same. You can read more about `update-alternatives` on the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/update-alternatives.8.html).

Comment: It's not working for me. PHPINFO is still showing always the same version, even after I try choosing.

Comment: I seem to have the same problem as well. I'll link back here when I've resolved it.

Answer (score 19):

I think you should try this

**From php5.6 to php7.1**

```
sudo a2dismod php5.6
sudo a2enmod php7.1
sudo service apache2 restart

sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.1
sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar7.1
sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar7.1
```

**From php7.1 to php5.6**

```
sudo a2dismod php7.1
sudo a2enmod php5.6
sudo service apache2 restart

sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar5.6
sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar5.6
```

Comment: Give enough explanation for your answers to understand why this code works and what it means.So that the answer will be useful for the users having the same issue. See the link to know how to write good answers.

Answer (score 14):

You can create a script to switch from versions: `sudo nano switch_php`
then type this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Switching to PHP$1..."
case $1 in
    "7")
        sudo a2dismod php5.6
        sudo a2enmod php7.0
        sudo service apache2 restart
        sudo ln -sfn /usr/bin/php7.0 /etc/alternatives/php;;
    "5.6")
        sudo a2dismod php7.0
        sudo a2enmod php5.6
        sudo service apache2 restart
        sudo ln -sfn /usr/bin/php5.6 /etc/alternatives/php;;
esac
echo "Current version: $( php -v | head -n 1 | cut -c-7 )"
```

exit and save
make it executable: `sudo chmod +x switch_php`

To execute the script just type `./switch_php [VERSION_NUMBER]` where the parameter is 7 or 5.6

That's it you can now easily switch form PHP7 to PHP 5.6!

Comment: Looks promising but what does 'n' flag does in ln command as you use "ln -sfn ..." . I have not been able to find that flag ("n")  anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: @FakharAnwar `man ln`: `-n, --no-dereference : treat LINK_NAME as a normal file if it is a symbolic link to a directory`

Answer (score 13):

this worked for me:-

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
```

just change the PHP  version to whichever version you need I have changed it to php7.4

Comment: For `php` cli, (`$ php -v`). It works for me too.

Comment: Good one and it worked for me too

Answer (score 10):

May be you might have an old PHP version like PHP 5.6 in your system and you installed PHP 7.2 too so thats multiple PHP in your machine. There are some applications which were developed when older PHP 5.6 was latest version, they are still live and you working on those applications, You might be working on Laravel simultaneously but Laravel requires PHP 7+ to get started. Getting the picture ?

In that case you can switch between the PHP versions to suit your requirements.

Switch From PHP 5.6 => PHP 7.2

Apache:-

```
sudo a2dismod php5.6
sudo a2enmod php7.2
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Command Line:-

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar7.2
sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar7.2
sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize7.2
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config7.2
```

And vice-versa, Switch From PHP 7.2 => PHP 5.6

Apache:-

```
sudo a2dismod php7.2
sudo a2enmod php5.6
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Command Line:-

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar5.6
sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar5.6
sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize5.6
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config5.6
```

Comment: The phpize and php-config commands are only available if you have phpX.Y-dev installed.

Answer (score 8):

> You can use below command lines to switch between two PHP version.

**E.g.**

**I want to switch `PHP Version` from `7.1` to `7.2` we can use below command**

```
sudo a2dismod php7.1 &&  sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2 && sudo a2enmod php7.2 && sudo service apache2 restart
```

`a2dismod` is use to disable the current php version and `a2enmod` is use to enable the version

Answer (score 5):

There are two methods to switch php versions on the command line ubuntu.

Run each command one by one and input the number of the php version you want to change.

**Method 1**

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
sudo update-alternatives --config phar
sudo update-alternatives --config phar.phar
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**Method 2**

If you want to change PHP 5.6 to 7.4 just run the below codes.

```
sudo a2dismod php5.6
sudo a2enmod php7.4
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If you want to change from PHP 7.4 to 5.6 run the below codes.

```
sudo a2dismod php7.4
sudo a2enmod php5.6
sudo service apache2 restart
```

For more information follow this link https://slaford.com/laravel/how-to-switch-php-versions-on-command-line-ubuntu/

Comment: This answer add nothing to what is already here. In addition, this is a 6 year old question; both the versions of PHP you mention in your answer are outdated and unsupported.

Answer (score 3):

Type given command in your terminal..

For disable the selected PHP version...

1. - **sudo a2dismod php5**
   - **sudo service apache2 restart**
2. For enable other PHP version....

   - **sudo a2enmod php5.6**
   - **sudo service apache2 restart**

It will upgrade Php version, same thing reverse if you want version downgrade, you can see it by PHP_INFO();

Answer (score 3):

Switch from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.2 using:

```
sudo a2dismod php5.6 && sudo a2enmod php7.2 && sudo service apache2 restart
```

---

Switch from PHP 7.2 to PHP 5.6 using:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.2 && sudo a2enmod php5.6 && sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 3):

I made a bash script to switch between different PHP versions on Ubuntu.

Hope it helps someone.

Here's the script:
(save it in /usr/local/bin/sphp.sh, don't forget to add +x flag with command: sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/sphp.sh)

```html
#!/bin/bash

# Usage
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
  echo "Usage: sphp [phpversion]"
  echo "Example: sphp 7.2"
  exit 1
fi

currentversion="`php -r \"error_reporting(0); echo str_replace('.', '', substr(phpversion(), 0, 3));\"`"
newversion="$1"

majorOld=${currentversion:0:1}
minorOld=${currentversion:1:1}
majorNew=${newversion:0:1}
minorNew=${newversion:2:1}

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  if [ "${newversion}" == "${currentversion}" ]; then
    echo "PHP version [${newversion}] is already being used"
    exit 1
  fi

  echo "PHP version [$newversion] found"
  echo "Switching from [php${currentversion}] to [php${newversion}] ... "

  printf "a2dismod php$majorOld.$minorOld ... "
  sudo a2dismod "php${majorOld}.${minorOld}"
  printf "[OK] and "

  printf "a2enmod php${newversion} ... "
  sudo a2enmod "php${majorNew}.${minorNew}"
  printf "[OK]\n"

  printf "update-alternatives ... "
  sudo update-alternatives --set php "/usr/bin/php${majorNew}.${minorNew}"
  printf "[OK]\n"

  sudo service apache2 restart
  printf "[OK] apache2 restarted\n"
else
  echo "PHP version $majorNew.$minorNew was not found."
  echo "Try \`sudo apt install php@${newversion}\` first."
  exit 1
fi

echo "DONE!"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use these open source PHP Switch Scripts, which were designed specifically for use in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

https://github.com/rapidwebltd/php-switch-scripts

There is a `setup.sh` script which installs all required dependencies for PHP 5.6, 7.0, 7.1 & 7.2. Once this is complete, you can just run one of the following switch scripts to change the PHP CLI and Apache 2 module version.

```
./switch-to-php-5.6.sh
./switch-to-php-7.0.sh
./switch-to-php-7.1.sh
./switch-to-php-7.2.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

From PHP 5.6 => PHP 7.1

```
$ sudo a2dismod php5.6
$ sudo a2enmod php7.1
```

for old linux versions

```
 $ sudo service apache2 restart
```

for more recent version

```
$ systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below script to switch between PHP version easily
I have included phpize configuration too.

https://github.com/anilkumararumulla/switch-php-version

Download the script file and run

```
sh switch.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

When installing laravel on Ubuntu 18.04, be default PHP 7.3.0RC3 install selected, but laravel and symfony will not install properly complaining about missin php-xml and php-zip, even though they are installed. You need to switch to php 7.1, using the instructions above or,

```
 sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.1
```

now, running laravel new blog, will proceed correctly

Answer (score 1):

please follow the steps :

```
i.e : your current version is : current_version = 7.3 , and you want to change it to : new_version = 7.2

1) sudo a2dismod php(current_version) 
2) sudo a2enmod php(new_version)
3) sudo update-alternatives --config php (here you need to select php version number) 
4) restart apache through : 
  sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart OR
  sudo service apache2 restart
```