# FatalErrorException in Inflector.php line 265: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{'

Tags: php, laravel

I went to update composer using

```
composer update
```

after update having the following error:

> FatalErrorException in Inflector.php line 265: syntax error,
>   unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{'

Please assist

Thanks in advance

Using Laravel Framework version 5.2.45

here is the composer code

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "*.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/Libraries/Functions.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Please see the function of inflector.php where error occures

```
public static function tableize(string $word) : string
    {
        return strtolower(preg_replace('~(?<=\\w)([A-Z])~', '_$1', $word));
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: The error is in the vendor/doctrine/inflector/lib within the inflector.php file

Comment: @jerodev using PHP Version 5.6.24

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It's a PHP version issue, update to PHP 7.0 and doctrine/inflector will work properly because doctrine/inflector 1.20 and above require PHP 7.

But if you want to stay at your current PHP version, you can downgrade the doctrine/inflector version by running the following commands:

1. Delete the composer.lock file

   `rm -f Composer.lock`
2. Delete the vendor

   `rm -R -f vendor`
3. `composer install`
4. Install the doctrine/inflector according to your php version

   `composer require doctrine/inflector:1.1.0`

doctrine/inflector:1.1.0 supports PHP 5.6 & above. If you have another version of php, you can refer to [this link](https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/inflector#v1.1.0)

Comment: How to change php version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42619312/switch-php-versions-on-commandline-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Thank you very much. I ran into similar issues while using Laravel 5.0 on PHP version 5.6. This did the trick.

Answer (score 5):

It's really obvious when you search for this file name and then start comparing package versions.

You are requiring `laravelcollective/html` at any version, so, for now, the latest version is `5.5.x`. This package in its turn requires `"doctrine/inflector": "~1.1",`, so any version below `2.0`, which is currently `1.3.0` **and requires PHP 7.0 or higher**.

If you look at the source of the latest `inflector.php`, you will see a return type is set on line 265, which is only supported in PHP 7.0 and up.

You are using PHP 5.6.24, so this code won't work on your system.

The simple way to fix your error is to use the `laravelcollective/html` version corresponding to your Laravel version. Which should probably be `5.2.*`.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I have a Laravel 5 app running on PHP 5.6. Composer requires laravelcollective/html version 5.0. Inflector for version 5.0 does not work on PHP 5.6. But Laravel 5.0's error handling doesn't work on PHP 7.0. A complete catch 22.

Answer (score 5):

I'm working on:

- Laravel 5.1
- PHP 5.6.36

My table name is like this: "test_meetings"

I solved the error specifying in testMeeting.php Model the table name:

```
protected $table = 'test_meetings';
```

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps anyone. I had a similar problem. My doctrine/inflector was expecting php>=7 for some reason (That's what was to found in the composer.json from doctrine/inflector). And this even though I had followed the instructions to install laravel 5.4.

I ran `rm -f Composer.lock` and `rm -R -f vendor` and then did a `composer install` after `vagrant ssh` to the homestead VM, which was using php 5.6.8 (originally I had run composer from my MacBook terminal, which was using php 7)

This cleared up the issues.

Answer (score 1):

Delete composer.lock file

```
`rm -f Composer.lock`
```

Delete the vendor folder

```
rm -R -f vendor
```

composer install

Then you can install a specific version of doctrine/inflector using composer
for example:

`composer require doctrine/inflector:1.2.0` (this will work with php 7.0)

Also, it helps me to resolve the build issue to upgrade carbon if you are using

```
composer require nesbot/carbon=1.29.*
```

Comment: inflector:1.2.0 also works with php 7.2. In my case downgrade inflector from 1.4.3 to 1.2.0 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

after

```
composer install
```

Try this after you have run the composer update:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by explicitly giving table name in model
protected $table = 'table_name';