# Laravel 5.3.31 installation not getting correct dependency versions

Tags: symfony, laravel-5, doctrine-orm, composer-php

Reference:
[FatalErrorException in Inflector.php line 265: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48380892/fatalerrorexception-in-inflector-php-line-265-syntax-error-unexpected-exp)

I have Laravel 5.3.31 installed along with PHP 5.6.32, however, it seems that composer cannot install the correct version of Doctrine and Symfony as I continue to get the error referenced above even after removing the vendor directory and composer.lock file and running `composer install`.

I have even modified the `composer.json` file as shown below.

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "*.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

I added this line `"laravelcollective/html": "*.*"` and modified these:
`"symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*"`
`"symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*"`

**What can I do to make sure I get the CORRECT versions of everything installed?**

When I run `composer install` I do see this on several lines, including all the ones for symfony:
`Installing...(vXXX): loading from cache`

Here's output from my install:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 58 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v2.4.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.7.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v3.1.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/translation (v3.1.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/routing (v3.1.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/process (v3.1.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing paragonie/random_compat (v2.0.11): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v3.1.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v3.4.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/log (1.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/debug (v3.1.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v3.1.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/finder (v3.1.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/console (v3.1.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.4.9): Loading from cache
  - Installing ramsey/uuid (3.7.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-color (0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter (v0.3.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir (0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing nesbot/carbon (1.22.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing mtdowling/cron-expression (v1.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing monolog/monolog (1.23.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing league/flysystem (1.0.42): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-util (v1.7.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php56 (v1.7.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing nikic/php-parser (v3.1.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing jeremeamia/superclosure (2.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing classpreloader/classpreloader (3.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing psy/psysh (v0.8.17): Loading from cache
  - Installing laravel/framework (v5.3.31): Loading from cache
  - Installing laravelcollective/html (v5.3.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing fzaninotto/faker (v1.7.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing hamcrest/hamcrest-php (v1.2.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing mockery/mockery (0.9.9): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/yaml (v3.3.16): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/version (1.0.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/global-state (1.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/recursion-context (1.0.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/exporter (1.2.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/environment (1.3.8): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/diff (1.4.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/comparator (1.2.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-text-template (1.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects (2.3.8): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-timer (1.0.9): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-file-iterator (1.4.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-token-stream (1.4.12): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-code-coverage (2.2.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing webmozart/assert (1.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-common (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpdocumentor/type-resolver (0.4.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (4.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpspec/prophecy (1.7.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/phpunit (4.8.36): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/css-selector (v2.8.34): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/dom-crawler (v2.8.34): Loading from cache
symfony/var-dumper suggests installing ext-symfony_debug ()
symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/config ()
symfony/routing suggests installing doctrine/annotations (For using the annotation loader)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/config (For using the all-in-one router or any loader)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection (For loading routes from a service)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/expression-language (For using expression matching)
paragonie/random_compat suggests installing ext-libsodium (Provides a modern crypto API that can be used to generate random bytes.)
symfony/event-dispatcher suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/browser-kit ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/class-loader ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/config ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection ()
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ircmaxell/random-lib (Provides RandomLib for use with the RandomLibAdapter)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ext-libsodium (Provides the PECL libsodium extension for use with the SodiumRandomGenerator)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ext-uuid (Provides the PECL UUID extension for use with the PeclUuidTimeGenerator and PeclUuidRandomGenerator)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing moontoast/math (Provides support for convertingUUID to 128-bit integer (in string form).)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ramsey/uuid-doctrine (Allows the use of Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid as Doctrine field type.)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ramsey/uuid-console (A console application for generating UUIDs with ramsey/uuid)
monolog/monolog suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Allow sending log messagesto AWS services like DynamoDB)
monolog/monolog suggests installing doctrine/couchdb (Allow sending log messages to a CouchDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-amqp (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server (1.0+ required))
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-mongo (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing graylog2/gelf-php (Allow sending log messages to a GrayLog2 server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing mongodb/mongodb (Allow sending log messagesto a MongoDB server via PHP Driver)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-amqplib/php-amqplib (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server using php-amqplib)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-console/php-console (Allow sending log messages to Google Chrome)
monolog/monolog suggests installing rollbar/rollbar (Allow sending log messagesto Rollbar)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ruflin/elastica (Allow sending log messagesto an Elastic Search server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing sentry/sentry (Allow sending log messages to a Sentry server)
league/flysystem suggests installing ext-ftp (Allows you to use FTP server storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v2 (Allows you to use S3 storage with AWS SDK v2)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (Allows you to use S3 storage with AWS SDK v3)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-azure (Allows you to use Windows Azure Blob storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-cached-adapter (Flysystemadapter decorator for metadata caching)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-eventable-filesystem (Allows you to use EventableFilesystem)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-rackspace (Allows you to use Rackspace Cloud Files)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-sftp (Allows you to use SFTP server storage via phpseclib)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-webdav (Allows you to useWebDAV storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-ziparchive (Allows you touse ZipArchive adapter)
league/flysystem suggests installing spatie/flysystem-dropbox (Allows you to use Dropbox storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing srmklive/flysystem-dropbox-v2 (Allows you to use Dropbox storage for PHP 5 applications)
psy/psysh suggests installing ext-pcntl (Enabling the PCNTL extension makes PsySH a lot happier :))
psy/psysh suggests installing ext-posix (If you have PCNTL, you'll want the POSIX extension as well.)
psy/psysh suggests installing ext-pdo-sqlite (The doc command requires SQLite to work.)
psy/psysh suggests installing hoa/console (A pure PHP readline implementation. You'll want this if your PHP install doesn't already support readline or libedit.)
laravel/framework suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Required to use the SQS queue driver and SES mail driver (~3.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing doctrine/dbal (Required to rename columns and drop SQLite columns (~2.4).)
laravel/framework suggests installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (Required to use the Mailgun and Mandrill mail drivers and the ping methods on schedules (~5.3|~6.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (Required to use the Flysystem S3 driver (~1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-rackspace (Required to use the Flysystem Rackspace driver (~1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing pda/pheanstalk (Required to use the beanstalk queue driver (~3.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing predis/predis (Required to use the redis cache and queue drivers (~1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing pusher/pusher-php-server (Required to use the Pusher broadcast driver (~2.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (Required to use psr7 bridging features (0.2.*).)
sebastian/global-state suggests installing ext-uopz (*)
phpunit/php-code-coverage suggests installing ext-xdebug (>=2.2.1)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing phpunit/php-invoker (~1.1)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize
Generating optimized class loader
The compiled class file has been removed.
```

Comment: Have you read the referenced question? It explains pretty clear whats going wrong...

Comment: Yes, I did, and I tried everything in the post. However, it continues to install Doctrine/Inflector version 1.3.0 which requires PHP 7.0+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it by adding this to my `composer.json`

```
"doctrine/inflector": "1.1.0"
```