# Change my PHP version on my Ubuntu server

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04

Currently using `PHP` version is `5.6.36` and I need to go down on version `5.3.29`.

Running `phpinfo()`on my script giving me this

[image]

While on my cli

[image]

For what I understand, I'm still using the version `5.6.36`.

Anyway to point the version to different installed php?

Comment: No, you need to upgrade to a supported version of PHP. PHP 5.6 reached end-of-life last December, and 5.3 went end-of-life five years ago.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switch php versions on commandline ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42619312/switch-php-versions-on-commandline-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CLI is referenced to PHP-CLI binaries. But Apache uses its internal module (libapache2-mod-php) to process PHP scripts. You have to downgrade the version of  libapache2-mod-php.

Try with below commands

```sh
# Install the old version of libapache-php
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5

# Disable PHP 5.6 module
sudo a2dismod php5.6

# Enable php 5.3 module
sudo a2enmod php5

# Restart Apache
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried using  `sudo a2enmod php5` but says `ERROR: Module php5 does not exist!` on the terminal

Comment: Did you install the module?

Comment: Nevermind I just missed the installation of module. thanks!