# How to fix Class 'DOMDocument' not found in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I updated recently from ubuntu 18.10 to 19.04 and as I try to signup for my laravel app I get: Class 'DOMDocument' not found.

I've already tried installing php-xml and php-dom and restarting apache as mentioned in other threads but for me its just not working.

Comment: After having tried to install `php-xml`, what happens? How exactly did you do that?

Comment: sudo apt-get install php-xml, my current php version is 7.3, but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Check your PHP version with `php -v` and install the version that fits your number. E.g. php7.2-xml. Otherwise the extensions may not be installed for the PHP version that you are currently using. You can also just simply change the used PHP version back to that one that you used before, which is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42619312/switch-php-versions-on-commandline-ubuntu-16-04/48336881). You may also need to install the corresponding libapache2 extension.

Comment: Have you checked through `phpinfo` that this extension was enabled? How exactly did you enable it after installing?

Comment: fixed the problem by removing all php files and installing them again, php7.3.