# How to upgrade php version from php 7.1* to php 7.2 in Ubuntu?

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04

In the Ubuntu machine, `PHP 7.1` is installed. Now I am working Laravel latest version. It requires PHP version PHP7.2*.

I run this command:

> apt-get install php7.2

But it is still showing php7.1 version.

> php -v

PHP 7.2.21-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Aug  7 2019 09:53:30) ( NTS )

Comment: https://ayesh.me/Ubuntu-PHP-7.2

Comment: I'm not sure I see the problem. The output you've quoted shows that you're running PHP 7.2.21.

Comment: Yes @duskwuff, you are right. I just restarted the server :)

Comment: You probably have multiple versions installed. See [Switch php versions on commandline ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42619312/switch-php-versions-on-commandline-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Thanks @Phil, Exactly this is I am looking :)

Comment: This works fine for me https://thishosting.rocks/install-php-on-ubuntu/