# after upgrade to php8.0, nginx still uses php7.2 for PHP-FPM

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-18.04

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with nginx/1.14.0.  I have been running PHP 7.2 but some of my web applications require a newer php for security reasons.

Since it is nginx, I use PHP-FPM.

I used apt to upgrade to the latest version of PHP.

```
# /usr/bin/php -v
PHP 8.0.2 (cli) (built: Feb 14 2021 14:21:15) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.2, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

So that looks right.  But the application still complains about PHP-FPM 7.2 and phpinfo confirms:

```
PHP Version 7.2.34-13+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
```

So it sounds like I should change the PHP conf file.  Here's what I get when I try to find it:

```
# locate php.conf | more
/etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf
```

OK.  So I seek php.ini:

```
# locate php.ini | more
/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini
/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini.orig
/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini.ucf-dist
/etc/php/8.0/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/8.0/fpm/php.ini
/usr/lib/php/7.2/php.ini-development
/usr/lib/php/7.2/php.ini-production
/usr/lib/php/7.2/php.ini-production.cli
/usr/lib/php/8.0/php.ini-development
/usr/lib/php/8.0/php.ini-production
/usr/lib/php/8.0/php.ini-production.cli
```

I am not seeing a conf file that would make the choice for NGINX or PHP where I would tell it to use PHP-FPM 8.0.

How do I get NGINX/PHP to use the new version of PHP that is on my server instead of the old one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in each server, you can define which version of PHP, Nginx should use:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
     include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
     fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
  }
```

or :

```
location ~ \.php$ {
     include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
     fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
  }
```

Comment: maybe you want to look at this link too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42619312/switch-php-versions-on-commandline-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Thank you.  This worked.  I got into the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/*` files and changed each instance where `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;` was stipulated and replaced it with `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;`.  And restarted the nginx service.  And now phpinfo() reports php 8.0 and my app that wanted PHP-FPM 8.0 is happy.  Thanks again!

Comment: @PHPdabbler you're welcome, but I suggest creating a file in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nuxt.info.conf (https://nuxt.info is my website, you make a file name for your website), and after that put all the codes related to your website inside it like https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment#nginx  Nginx will read all the files with .conf suffix in the 'conf.d' folder

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the relevant PHP packages. You update the `cli` package, but that's not enough.

Check which packages are installed for 7.2:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinst | grep php | grep 7.2
```

and if, say, you find `php7.2-foo`, try installing `php8.0-foo`. Try then also removing the 7.2 version.

Be sure to run an `apt-get update` beforehand.

Some packages (I think one is `xdebug`, and maybe `redis`?) have weird dependencies, in that installing the 8.0 will *also* (re)install the 7.2. That's okay. But you'll probably just need the FPM one(s), and those should be trouble-free.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  I chose to try the other answer first because it seemed easier and less risky.

Comment: That's okay. But the "risk" is truly negligible, you probably currently just have two separate PHP-FPM installations and one PHP-CLI installation (the command above will tell you whether this is the case). At worst, you get some extra disk space used for modules you're not really using - which, on the other hand, is the situation you're in now :-)

Comment: I forgot! - all the above holds, *unless* you **need** two different versions of PHP installed, which **is** a common requirement (if you, for example, need to maintain an older PHP codebase together with a recent one).

When that is the case, my solution is worthless and actually damaging, as it will disable older PHPs; and you need to tune Nginx conf files instead (@SamRaskul's answer).