# Upgrade PHP 7.3 to 7.4 in Laravel Project folder

Tags: php, laravel

I have cloned the Laravel project and want to upgrade the PHP version in the Laravel project from 7.3 to 7.4. Because when I run `composer install`, it shows an error like this:

`Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.4.0". You are running 7.3.24`

I have installed PHP 7.4 on my laptop, when I check on terminal `php -v` it shows `7.4`, but when I check `php -v` in laravel project it show `7.3`. please anyone can tell me how to update the PHP version on the Laravel project.

Comment: it's not related to the laravel project. you have two php installation, CLI and FPM, CLI is for console commands. Check you vhost file if the version is pecified there. If not , we need more details about your installation and the server you are using. Or bypass the composer error as the asnwer shows you.

Answer (score 0):

Run on your terminal:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

Then select the version you want to use

[Switch php versions on commandline ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42619312/switch-php-versions-on-commandline-ubuntu-16-04)