# Ubuntu terminal shows php version 7.4 but browser shows php version 7.2

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I'm in need of some desperate help. Moderators, please don't flag this question for being duplicate. I'm only asking here after I couldn't find any solution(s) for my case on previous question.

I've been stuck on this for 2 days now. I wanted to change the php version used on my Ubuntu from 7.2 to 7.4. I tried all the steps that I can google and also that I can find here in Stack Overflow and all I was able to do was switch php version on terminal to 7.4 but the browser still displays version 7.2 when displaying php info with phpinfo();

For your information I've PHP versions 5.6, 7.0, 7.2, 7.4 & 8.0 installed on my Ubuntu system.

So, can any help me switch my php version on the browser from 7.2 to 7.4? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can have different versions of PHP for CLI and browser. Which web server are you using, Apache or nginx?

Comment: try using `phpinfo()` to see where your PHP is installed at. then compare it with `whereis php`

Comment: You've changed `php-cli` version, you still need to update your `php-fpm` version, which depends on your current install process.

Comment: Did you try ALL of these possible solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42619312/switch-php-versions-on-commandline-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Have you tried removing the versions you don't need from your system? That could help to remove irrelevant configuration files

Comment: How are you running PHP in your Apache? As an Apache module or as FPM/FastCGI

Comment: @aynber I'm using Apache web server

Comment: @RiggsFolly apart from the one using bash script, yes I tried almost all.

Comment: @RiggsFolly The Server API info shows FPM/FastCGI displayed via phpinfo()

Comment: @NicoHaase no. I need other versions as well for my other projects.

Comment: Did you try `a2disconf php-7.2-fpm` and then `sudo a2enconf php7.4-fpm`

Comment: @RiggsFolly nope. But just tried and they generate Conf php7.2-fpm and Conf php7.4-fpm does not exist! error