# Laravel migration not working in docker, SerializableClosure error

Tags: laravel, docker

I am running into an issue when i log into the docker container and run

> php artisan migrate --seed

I've had this working before so i'm not sure why this is happening:

> Opis\Closure\SerializableClosure implements the Serializable
> interface, which is deprecated. Implement __serialize() and
> __unserialize() instead (or in addition, if support for old PHP versions is necessary)

In order this is what i run:

FROM MAC: composer install
FROM MAC: sail up -d
FROM MAC: sail exec container-id bash
FROM CONTAINER: npm install
FROM CONTAINER: php artisan migrate --seed

The container runs on PHP 8.1 with MySql on ubuntu. Composer install worked from outside the container to create the vendor folder, here is the composer.json if it's any help:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "ext-dom": "20031129",
        "darkaonline/l5-swagger": "^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.40",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.10",
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/package-versions-deprecated": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

and docker-compose:

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    acklams-api:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - acklams-mysql
    acklams-mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
          retries: 3
          timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
```

I can't be sure but i think it should be installing php 8.0 not 8.1, the image: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0 ?

Below is an image of what i see in the container, i run php -v which shows 8.1 instead of 8.0, and the error at the end when i try to migrate:

[image]

**EDIT**

I noticed it had installed 8.1 and 8.0, so i just switched and it now works. Weird how that just randomly started happening.

Comment: @MaikLowrey try what mate? You just quoted me? I was saying that the docker compose has the context to 8.0 but when i run php -v it shows 8.1 and i think this may be why the error is happening. So any idea why it's installing the incorrect php version? - i also added a screenshot

Comment: Inside the container, that's where it's installed php 8.1 even though the docker file says 8.0

Comment: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/15538 and https://zubair.dev/blog/how-closures-are-serialized-in-laravel-using-opis-closure-package

Comment: I noticed it had installed 8.1 and 8.0, so i just switched and it now works

Comment: "try it" that was what I meant earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed it had installed 8.1 and 8.0, so i just switched and it now works

Comment: perfect! and thanks for feedback

Comment: I’d still like to know why it installed both when the config specifically says 8.0

Comment: maybe check you dockerfile!? Can you share it in your question?

Comment: If you need help switching, run `sudo update-alternatives --config php`. (ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48336881/1277350)