# How to specify php version for specific project in laravel on windows 11

Tags: php, laravel

Here I'm working on a simple laravel project which uses php version of 7.1.3 and I have php version 8.1.2 installed on my computer.

How do I specify specific php version for different projects?

I tried to re-install php 7.1 version but I have other projects on my computer which uses 8 or higher.

Can I specify specific php version for different laravel projects?

Comment: I think it is definitely what you need https://stackoverflow.com/a/48336881/7155723

Comment: Thanks but @OdinThunder so this is for Ubuntu only, how can I do in windows?

Comment: on ubuntu install php version you're looking forward to working with then run command: ``sudo update-alternatives --config php`` it'll show you versions of php you've installed and select version from list. for windows can you tell if you're using xampp or installed php?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tell Composer to use Different PHP Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750250/tell-composer-to-use-different-php-version)

Comment: `composer config platform.php 7.1.3`

Comment: It may help you https://medium.com/@sivaschenko/apache-running-multiple-php-versions-simultaneously-570fc1541580

Comment: You all are suggesting me for Ubuntu, but I'm using windows 11 

Comment: I recommend you update your question and describe your environment (OS, nginx/apache, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

### Use Laragon

**I don't know if it is possible with other stacks but Laragon is a lightweight ans performant option.**

As described [here](https://medium.com/@oluwaseye/add-different-php-versions-to-your-laragon-installation-d2526db5c5f1) it's easy and there are few steps.

1. Install Laragon as your `LAMPP` or `LEMMP` stack for windows
2. Download your desired PHP version from [official website](https://windows.php.net/download/)
3. Extract downloaded zip in PHP folder within your Laragon installation.
4. Right-click on the Laragon icon in your stystem tray. Navigate to PHP and choose your version!
5. Restart Laragon and done!

[image]

The default installation path is:

```
C:\laragon\bin\php\
```

**Laragon will pick up the folder name as the identifier.**

**Note:** You Can config `apache` or `nginx` to serve each directory with its own version but it is not included in this post. you should learn it from official documentations.

Answer (score -1):

I think Docker is the best solution for you, because it doesn't matter which php version is installed on your computer. Here is some link for 'Dockerizing' your Laravel application. Hope this helps :)

- https://medium.com/geekculture/the-easiest-way-to-dockerize-your-laravel-application-94977fe2ed6d

Comment: Answer is not related with the problem that the OP is facing