# Apache server not using the correct version of php

Tags: php, apache, lamp

I want to switch my apache2 server from php5.6 to php7.4, following this stackoverflow [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42619312/switch-php-versions-on-commandline-ubuntu-16-04). However when I switched from php5.6 to php7.4, I get php5.6 then when I switched from php7.4 to php5.6, I get php7.2 instead. It wasn't like this before, please advice thank you.

php5.6 to php7.4 ( server used php5.6 )
[image]

php7.4 to php5.6 ( server used php7.2 )
[image]

Comment: That looks like some Linux based system. So I assume you can simply use your systems software management system (which flavor that is depends on the distribution you are using) to remove the unwanted php versions and install exactly one desired version. Along with the required php modules and the FPM module which you seem to be using for the integration into the apache http server.

Comment: There seems to be a mismatch of version 7.4 and 7.2??  Have you tried "restart" rather then "reload".  Also, I'm sure apachectl is preferred over systemctl these days (for Apache)?

Comment: thanks arkascha, mike. full uninstall + reinstall

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the cause but a full uninstall and reinstall of php on my ubuntu fixed this.